# Pattur aval assur

Tags: talmud-gemara

Why does the *gemara* only use the phrase *pattur aval assur* in reference to laws of shabbat? Regarding laws of other holidays, the *gemara* says *assur* from the *torah* or *assur* from the *rabanan*. Why then did the *gemara* only by *shabbat* discussions decide to use *chayav* to refer to *assur* from the *torah*, and *assur* to refer to *assur* from the *rabanan*?

Note that sorcery is the only other topic in the *gemara* that also uses the terminology of *pattur aval assur*.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of where you think it should be used but isn't?

Comment: More Katan 12a-b uses this by Chol Hamoed.

Answer (score 1):

*Patur aval asur* means that a person is not allowed to do the action but is not required to bring a korbon chatas if not done deliberately nor chayav kareis if done deliberately. Since one cannot be brought before the court, the term is used specifically for actions of this type. If a person is able to be brought before a court then the other terms are used.